# How to access nested elements in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of items (divs) with a button. When I click on one of this buttons I can access the element using

```
$event.currentTarget
```

that returns some thing like

```
<div ng-click="myFunc()">
  <i class="someclass"></i>
  <span>bla bla</span>
</div>
```

how can I access  and  elements to modify attributes like class?

Comment: Don't. Use existing directives like `ng-class` or `ng-if` etc in your html templates.

Comment: I need to do this on click...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### template

```
<div ng-click="myFunc($event)">
  <i class="someclass"></i>
  <span>bla bla</span>
</div>
```

#### controller

```
$scope.myFunc(event) {
   var elem = angluar.element(event.currentTarget);
   elem.children(".someclass").removeClass("someclass")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't. Use existing directives like `ng-class` or `ng-if`, etc in your html templates.

```
<div ng-click="clicked = true">
  <span ng-class="{'someclass': clicked}">bla bla</span>
</div>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-mqsdhr)

---

Although you can get the html dom element and edit it you should only do this as a last option and other angularjs supported methods have failed or are not supported.